# Get more debug info from AxHost?

Tags: c#, exception, activex, hresult, axhost

I'm trying to deploy an application which uses an library that embeds an ActiveX control with AxHost in C#.

When I run the installed app on our test rig I catch and present the following exception:

```
Unexpected exception.

This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   at ....InitializeComponent()
   at ...
```

I googled 0x800736B1, so I know that it means that a file could not be loaded.

The big Q right now is how to find out *which* file it is that cant be loaded.

Is there some sort of logging function I can turn on, or is there maybe som way I can get more info from the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's your ActiveX code this will be hard or impossible.  I suggest using a tool like [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find which file handle fails.  If you have the code you can run it in debug mode, or improve it's logging.

Of course you could always try

> Reinstalling the application may fix
>   this problem